# I cannot perform "Quick Fix" in VS Code using the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + .`

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I cannot perform "Quick Fix" in VS Code using the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + .`.

I have tried removing all extensions, re-installing VS code, restoring defaults and removing all other bindings for `Ctrl + .`. Nothing seems to work. I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04 and VS Code 1.78.2-1683731010. I tried to fix it in the "Keyboard Shortcuts" section by re-mapping the shortcut. I noticed that `Ctrl + .` get rendered as `Ctrl + unknown`. But when I only press `.` it gets rendered as `.`. I also checked to see if there were default bindings for `Ctrl + .` in Ubuntu itself but couldn't find any.

Comment: It does. I found this to just turn it off. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/692237/ctrl-displays-e-character-and-captures-the-keyboard-shortcut

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `Ctrl + .` is a shortcut for emojis in Ubuntu and is causing the issue.

Comment: Use `dconf editor` as explained here https://askubuntu.com/a/1045916 to change or remove hotkey